# Symfony forms: converting an ID back to an Entity before persisting to database

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have a User entity and a Role entity, with a many-to-many mapping between them. When displaying the HTML form that handles the creation of a new User, I list the available Roles that can be assigned to the User as per the following code fragment (I've implemented the __toString() function to correctly display the Role).

```
->add('roles', 'entity', array(
                'class'     => 'Acme\UserBundle\Entity\Role',
                'expanded'  => true,
                'multiple'  => true,
            ))
```

This works, at least to the extent where it correctly displays the available Roles along with checkboxes to select which Roles should be assigned to the User. **The value of each checkbox refers to the ID of that Role.**

However, when I select one of these checkboxes and try to save the form, I receive the following error:

```
This value should be of type Acme\UserBundle\Entity\Role.
```

Clearly, the problem is that I'm just submitting the IDs of the Roles, and somewhere in my PHP code I need to take those IDs and convert them into actual entities, instead of trying to just persist the IDs themselves. How and where do I do this?

For completeness, I've included my current code below:

**User.php**

```
/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="User")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Acme\UserBundle\Entity\UserRepository")
 */
class User implements AdvancedUserInterface
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="guid")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="UUID")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=25, unique=true)
     */
    private $username;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=64)
     */
    private $password;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Role", inversedBy="users")
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="User_Role")
     * @Assert\Type(type="Acme\UserBundle\Entity\Role")
     */
    private $roles;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->roles = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    /**
     * @inheritDoc
     */
    public function getUsername()
    {
        return $this->username;
    }

    /**
     * @inheritDoc
     */
    public function getPassword()
    {
        return $this->password;
    }

    /**
     * @inheritDoc
     */
    public function getRoles()
    {
        return $this->roles->toArray();
    }

    /**
     * @inheritDoc
     */
    public function eraseCredentials()
    {
    }

    /**
     * @inheritDoc
     */
    public function isAccountNonExpired()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * @inheritDoc
     */
    public function isAccountNonLocked()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * @inheritDoc
     */
    public function isCredentialsNonExpired()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * @inheritDoc
     */
    public function isEnabled()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return guid
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set username
     *
     * @param string $username
     * @return User
     */
    public function setUsername($username)
    {
        $this->username = $username;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Set password
     *
     * @param string $password
     * @return User
     */
    public function setPassword($password)
    {
        $this->password = $password;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Add roles
     *
     * @param Role $roles
     * @return User
     */
    public function addRole(Role $roles)
    {
        $this->roles[] = $roles;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove roles
     *
     * @param Role $roles
     */
    public function removeRole(Role $roles)
    {
        $this->roles->removeElement($roles);
    }
}
```

**Role.php**

```
<?php

/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="Role")
 * @ORM\Entity()
 */
class Role implements RoleInterface
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="guid")
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="UUID")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=30)
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="role", type="string", length=20, unique=true)
     */
    private $role;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="User", mappedBy="roles")
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="User_Role")
     */
    private $users;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->users = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function __toString()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    /**
     * @see RoleInterface
     */
    public function getRole()
    {
        return $this->role;
    }

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return guid
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set name
     *
     * @param string $name
     * @return Role
     */
    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get name
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    /**
     * Set role
     *
     * @param string $role
     * @return Role
     */
    public function setRole($role)
    {
        $this->role = $role;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Add users
     *
     * @param User $users
     * @return Role
     */
    public function addUser(User $users)
    {
        $this->users[] = $users;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove users
     *
     * @param User $users
     */
    public function removeUser(User $users)
    {
        $this->users->removeElement($users);
    }

    /**
     * Get users
     *
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection 
     */
    public function getUsers()
    {
        return $this->users;
    }
}
```

**UserType.php**

```
class UserType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('username', 'text', array(
                'label'     => 'Username'
            ))
            ->add('password', 'password', array(
                'label'     => 'Password'
            ))
            ->add('email', 'email', array(
                'label'     => 'Email Address'
            ))
            ->add('roles', 'entity', array(
                'label'     => 'Roles',
                'class'     => 'Acme\UserBundle\Entity\Role',
                'property'  => 'name',
                'expanded'  => true,
                'multiple'  => true,
            ))
        ;
    }

    /**
     * @param OptionsResolverInterface $resolver
     */
    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'Acme\UserBundle\Entity\User'
        ));
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return 'acme_userbundle_user';
    }
}
```

**UserRepository.php**

```
/**
 * UserRepository
 *
 * This class was generated by the Doctrine ORM. Add your own custom
 * repository methods below.
 */
class UserRepository extends EntityRepository implements UserProviderInterface
{
    /**
     * @inheritDoc
     */
    public function loadUserByUsername($username)
    {
        $q = $this
            ->createQueryBuilder('u')
            ->where('u.username = :username OR u.email = :email')
            ->setParameter('username', $username)
            ->setParameter('email', $username)
            ->getQuery();

        try {
            // The Query::getSingleResult() method throws an exception
            // if there is no record matching the criteria
            $user = $q->getSingleResult();
        }
        catch (NoResultException $e) {
            $message = sprintf(
                'Unable to find an active admin AcmeUserBundle:User object identified by "%s".',
                $username
            );
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException($message, 0, $e);
        }

        return $user;
    }

    /**
     * @inheritDoc
     */
    public function refreshUser(UserInterface $user)
    {
        $class = get_class($user);
        if (!$this->supportsClass($class)) {
            throw new UnsupportedUserException(
                sprintf(
                    'Instances of %s are not supported',
                    $class
                )
            );
        }

        return $this->find($user->getId());
    }

    /**
     * @inheritDoc
     */
    public function supportsClass($class)
    {
        return $this->getEntityName() === $class
            || is_subclass_of($class, $this->getEntityName());
    }
}
```

Comment: If you're binding the user entity to the form, the roles should be automatically translated into entities.  Can you post the code you're using to save the form?  Also - have you defined your own data transformers?

Comment: I'll update my question with the code I'm using. Also, no I haven't defined any data transformers. Do I need to?

Comment: No, but if you had it might have interfered with the automatic transformation.

Comment: Oh I see. No, I've used used the standard CRUD template that was auto-generated by Symfony and Doctrine, and made a couple of changes, such as adding a toString() function to the Role.php, and customizing the form output a bit.

Comment: I figured it out. What a careless mistake... Will add it as an answer now. Thanks for putting me onto the right track. Now I know that the translation from ID to actual entity occurs automatically.

Answer (score 1):

In User.php, above the $roles variable, the following assertion should be removed:

```
@Assert\Type(type="Acme\UserBundle\Entity\Role")
```

The $roles variable is in fact an array, and not of type Role, hence the validation failed.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to change the `buildForm` in UserType.php to the following, because Roles are not as separate type while they are ArrayCollection or I believe should be just array (you can check your entity and what type you return for `getRoles()`

```
$builder
        ->add('username', 'text', array(
            'label'     => 'Username'
        ))
        ->add('password', 'password', array(
            'label'     => 'Password'
        ))
        ->add('email', 'email', array(
            'label'     => 'Email Address'
        ))
        ->add('roles_collection', 'entity', array(
            'label'     => 'Roles',
            'type'      => new RoleType(),
            'property'  => 'name',
            'expanded'  => true,
            'multiple'  => true,
        ));
```

And add the below function to your Roles entity:

```
public function getRolesCollection()
{
    //this returns a collection
    return $this->roles;
}
```

And I am sure you have below function in your Roles entity which returns array not ArrayCollection of roles

```
public function getRoles()
{
    return $this->roles->toArray();
}
```

Just keep in mind my solution is that if you want to keep your form builder to add Role as collection not array, other wise the previous answer is also a help for you